# Not able to connect to an IP from databricks notebook in azure

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, firewall, ping, network-security-groups

I am trying to connect to a server which is on prem network using a databricks notebook. But I get error saying that "failed to connect to address. UNAVAIALABLE Socket closed".
I pinged to the server IP and it got failed.
[image]

I wanted to add this IP as exception to databricks so that it can connect to it.
After learning the options to configure network configs, I understand that it needs to be added as a rules in network security group. So I added it as a outbound rule with below configs :

[image]

But I am still not able to successfully ping the server IP.

I have shared all the details. Can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong?